# Notebook doesn`t turn on

Tags: boot, system-installation

So, my brother gave me his old notebook since he got a new one. It had Windows 10.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from my pendrive, choose the option to wipe all disc and install Ubuntu. Logged in on my home wifi and all, the installation seemed OK from start to end. Then it asked me to restart and the notebook doesn't turn on anymore. It gives me a black screen and keeps like flashing, turning off and on again.

If I press <kbd>F12</kbd> after the motherboard logo and choose to try the Ubuntu from pen drive it runs nicely.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Boot from the USB drive, and when you see the guy and keyboard, press enter, select a language and press enter, and select "Check disk for defects" and press enter.  This will make sure the image on the USB drive is intact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter BIOS (Usually F1 & F2)

Look for something called Secureboot and DISABLE.

(Also it´s not long until the release of 16.04, i suggest you install that)
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) is still in beta development state and not officially recommended. There are still a lot of bug reports coming in for it. While it's easier to update from a beta version to the final version of the same major release than upgrading to a different release altogether, I wouldn't flat out recommend the former to a novice user.

Comment: Duly noted, i was also thinking it contained a newer installer.